# How do you check an array to see if it has more even values than odd?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer, boolean

I'm working on a project and one of the things I need to do is create a method where it takes in an int array and checks it to see if it has more even than odds. The method needs to be `boolean` and take in an `int[]`

I know I need to use a `for` statement with something like

```java
for (int i = 0; i < hasMoreEvenThanOdd.length; i++)
```

or

```java
for (int values : hasMoreEvenThanOdd)
```

But I'm confused on what the for loop would contain something like this?

```java
if (numerator % denomEven == 0) {
    boolean res = true;
    return res;
} else if (numerator % denomOdd == 0) {
    boolean res = true;
    return res;
} else {
    boolean res = false;
    return res;
}
```

and I'm not sure how to get the math to check out in the end.

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @NomadMaker I agree with you, if you read my initial answer, I tried to provide only tips so that OP could get to the answer by themself. What happen? OP select the answer that gives away the solution and that answer got an upvote so it looks like the community does not care about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like that:

```java
public boolean checkIfHasMoreEvenThanOdds(int[] hasMoreEvenThanOdds) {
    int even = 0;
    int odds = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hasMoreEvenThanOdds.length; i++) {
        if (hasMoreEvenThanOdds[i] % 2 == 0) {
            even++;
        } else {
            odds++;
        }
    }
    if (even > odds) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method will return true if it has more even than odds, and false if the opposite. This code "parse" the array, and checks element by element if it is or not odd, and increments in a variable (odd or even). By final, it checks which one is greater than, and return in base of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over this array and [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) only even numbers, and then check whether their [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--) is more than half of the array:

```java
public static boolean hasMoreEvenThanOdd(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).count() > arr.length / 2;
}
```

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hasMoreEvenThanOdd(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7})); // false
    System.out.println(hasMoreEvenThanOdd(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6})); // true
    System.out.println(hasMoreEvenThanOdd(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5})); // false
    System.out.println(hasMoreEvenThanOdd(new int[]{2, 3, 4})); // true
    System.out.println(hasMoreEvenThanOdd(new int[]{2, 3})); // false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if
Sum all evens

Second if
Sum all odds

Compare if evens is more than odds
Return true is true

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is iterate over all elements in the array for instance using:

```
for (int values : hasMoreEvenThanOdd)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < hasMoreEvenThanOdd.length; i++)
```

then keep track of the even numbers for instance:

```
if (values % 2 == 0)
   total_even_numbers++;
```

**Outside the loop:**

In the end, to get the total of `odd` numbers you just need to subtract from the size of the array (*i.e.,*  `hasMoreEvenThanOdd.length`) the total of `even` numbers that you have found.

Finally, just compare the two values, and return accordingly.

An example:

```
public boolean hasMoreEvenThanOdd(int[] values){
    int even = 0;
    for (int value : values)
        if (value % 2 == 0)
            even++;
    return even > (values.length - even);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other comments, you would need to maintain two variabled `nEven` (number of even numbers) and `nOdd` (number of odd numbers) while iterating the array and increment depending upon whether item at a specified index is even or odd. If you're using Java 8+, you can use streams to filter odd/even numbers and count them:

```java
public static boolean containsMoreEvenThanOdd(int[] array) {
    long nEven = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).count();
    long nOdd = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).count();

    return nEven > nOdd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean counting the number of even and odd values in your array.

If so, this might help you:

```
for(..........) {
    if (hasMoreEvenThanOdd[i] % 2 == 0) 
    {
        even++; 
    }
    else
    {
        odd++;
    }
}

return even > odd;
```

Answer (score 0):

*separate even and odd values into two groups with* `Collectors.partitioningBy`

```
public boolean checkIfHasMoreEvenThanOdds(int[] evenAndOdds) {
  Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.of( evenAndOdds )
      .boxed().collect( partitioningBy( n -> (n & 1) == 0 ) );
  return(map.get( true ).size() > map.get( false ).size());
}
```